# Ruby Tempfile download missing headers

Tags: ruby, sinatra, temporary-files

I'm working on a file upload feature in a Sinatra app. It's small and simple and was done just using Ruby's File class and saving a temporary file to a directory by hand. I'm trying to implement the same functionality using Tempfile.

I've got the upload working, but now when I click a link to download the file, the filename is just a number. It downloads and reads the file correctly but it doesn't retain the filename or type of file. Before I made my changes the file would open up in the browser by redirecting to the newly uploaded file's endpoint on the server. I'd like to get that functionality back.

My code is as follows:

```
post "/positions/:id/attachment" do
  html_settings
  new_data = post_data
  if params[:file_attachment][:file].present?
    file      = params[:file_attachment][:file]
    # file looks like this when uploaded:
    #{:filename=>"Screen Shot 2013-11-26 at 4.36.13 PM.png", :type=>"image/png", :name=>"file_attachment[file]", :tempfile=>#<File:/var/folders/85/0kp_g81s1ws16zths3s8d9p80000gn/T/RackMultipart20131127-2757-1kdficq>, :head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_attachment[file]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2013-11-26 at 4.36.13 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n"}

    # Tempfile object
    temp_file = Tempfile.new(file[:filename], 'uploads') # Create tempfile, save to uploads folder

    begin
      write_tempfile(file, temp_file)
      new_data['file_attachment']['file'] = temp_file
      new_data['multipart'] = true

      # At this point, the new_data hash looks the same except for a small difference in the path name
      # Before tempfile - {"file_attachment"=> {"display_name"=>"test","file"=>#<File:uploads/Screen Shot 2013-11-26 at 11.35.36 AM.png>}, "id"=>"1"}
      # With tempfile - {"file_attachment"=> {"display_name"=>"test", "file"=>#<File:/path/to/uploads/Screen Shot 2013-11-26 at 4.36.13 PM.png20131127-2757-eb6w6r>}, "id"=>"1", "multipart"=>true}

      response = api_post(attachment_upload_endpoint(params[:id]), new_data)
    ensure
      delete_tempfile(temp_file)
      response
    end
  end
end
```

Helper methods:

```
def write_tempfile(file, temp)
  file[:tempfile].rewind # Rewind before reading
  temp.write(file[:tempfile].read) # Write to the temp file
  temp.rewind # Rewind in order to be read
end

def delete_tempfile(temp_file)
  #close! calls #close AND #unlink. #unlink deletes the file
  temp_file.close!
end
```

After the file is uploaded there is a link to https://myserver.com/positions/1/file_attachments/46

Does anyone understand why now, when I click on that link, it downloads the file with the filename 46 and not in the browser anymore?

I also get this notification in the console: 
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type binary/octet-stream

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the file extension by using the array version of Tempfile.new? http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-c-new

Comment: That works if I know the extension. I just tried with a png and it worked. But what about if I dont know it? Does that mean I have to parse the possible file extensions I want?

Comment: I just got it working with some extra parsing for the extension. I'll make an edit

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with some extra parsing for the extension:

```
  ext = file[:filename].split('.').last
  temp_file = Tempfile.new([file[:filename], ".#{ext}"])
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, perhaps [File.extname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-extname) will be a little more robust.